# Can all Java applet run on 64bit JRE enabled browser?

Tags: java, applet, java-8

I have a java applet, which doesn't run on 64bit systems (browsers & OS are 64Bit) but works perfectly fine on 32bit Client systems. Why the applet fails to execute on 64Bit client system ?

Comment: Do any *other* Java applets work on the problem system? What about using the applet viewer directly?

Comment: The message is just a *warning*. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/manifest.html#app_name You have to do more analysis to get why you applet doesn’t work. The output you have posted does not give any hint.

Comment: yes., message was just a warning., I updated my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such thing as 32-bit Java applet.

Java sources are compiled into byte code which does not have a "property" of 32 bit or 64 bit. Only the JVM has variants of 32 bit or 64 bit.

So as long as your applet only contains Java code (and no native libraries), it should run on both 32 bit and 64 bit JVM's no matter what you used to compile your sources.

Answer (score 0):

1: If the applet is pure Java (i.e. no native code), then it does not matter "for which" CPU it was compiled, because *there's no machine code*. Java bytecode is fully portable — it only requires that you have a JVM not older that was the target while compiling.
2: Your error is about missing "Application-Name manifest attribute" as your log says, this is not related to CPU architecture, and this applet won't work on x86_64, too.

Comment: It actually works on other systems which are on 32bit., that's the reason I doubt the architecture.,little weird error though

Comment: Try unpacking .jar file and look what's inside. Is there a manifest, and what does it contain. @SairamKrish